# Bind lines together with css or html

Tags: html, css

I want 2 lines to be bound together, no matter the width of the viewing device.

Reason is line2 always explains line1 etc. They have to be bound responsively, meaning if width of screen changes, they still have to be bound.

It would also be possible to bind by word, meaning 1st line and 2nd line word are always under each other (centered by the longest width of those two).

**UPDATED**

Is there a solution with css/html ??

```css
#container div:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: gray;color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div>This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.</div>
<div>This line is bound to line1 no matter whatThis line is bound to line1 no matter whatThis line is bound to line1 no matter whatThis line is bound to line1 no matter what</div>
<div>This line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main content.</div>
<div>This line is bound and explains content of line 1.This line is bound and explains content of line 1.This line is bound and explains content of line 1.</div>
  
  </div>
```

To make it clear: when you run the above snippet. Line 1 is rendered in two-lines next to each other.

I want it to be always 1 line from Div1 and the next line from Div2.

So it should look like this:

```html
This is my text, it tells a story about a cat which was 
这是我的文字，它讲述了一个故事一只猫是什么哪
always angry and attacked even humans. One day the cat 
总是生气，甚至攻击人类。有一天，猫
```

The first line is the english text and the next line shall ALWAYS be the translated text. It is hard to make this responsive since the width of the lines varies.

Is there a way

Comment: This could mean a variety of things

Comment: Can you explain clearly what exactly you are lookign for

Comment: What do you mean by "bound"? Could you maybe provide some pictures?

Comment: @T.Bragg i hope my update makes it more clear. thx for pointing out.

Comment: @Geeky thanks letting me know,  i hope my UPDATE explains better now...

Comment: @GeromeGerardo This made it clearer and I have an answer for you at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

Hover on the container to see it changing the width.

There are several tricks, but the main idea is to float both element side by side, with an line-width increased, and then make them overlap as appropiate with a transform.

Since every div takes only half the width of the container, set the container to width 200% to restore the apparent width

```css
#container {
  width: 200%;
  transition: width 15s;
}

#container:hover {
  width: 100%;  
}

#container div:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: gray;
  color:white;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-right: -50%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

#container div:nth-child(even){
  position: relative;
  top: 2.1em;
  float: right;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#container div {
  line-height: 2.2em;  
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div>This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness.</div>
<div>This line is bound to line1 no matter whatThis line is bound to line1 no matter whatThis line is bound to line1 no matter whatThis line is bound to line1 no matter what</div>
<div>This line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main contentThis line is the main content.</div>
<div>This line is bound and explains content of line 2.This line is bound and explains content of line 1.This line is bound and explains content of line 1.</div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: omg. This is so amazing. I searched all the web 12h yesteday but couldn't find this or something similar. I will go test it further and than accept your answer if it is how it looks! Amazing!!

Comment: Your snippet is one of a kind. Genius. Unfortunately i can't upvote yet (less than 15 points), but be assured about my thanks and an additional accepted answer. Best Regards

Comment: Happy that it helped you !

Answer (score 0):

Once text is longer than its parent container's 100% width, it will by default wrap the text to a new line so it remains visible. This is what causes your issue (changing the alignment of the bound line of text below). Here is one possible work around in which I have restructured your HTML and added some CSS which may be a starting point to help you achieve what you want.

```css
.no-wrap {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="no-wrap">
    This is line 1 text, we assume responsiveness<br>
    This line is bound to line1 no matter what
  </div>
  <div class="no-wrap">This line is the main content<br>
    This line is bound and explains content of line 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't act the way required if we extend the text to 2 lines. see here https://jsfiddle.net/ggo5wq58/. It cuts the content

Answer (score 0):

You could use a span tag to make it look like you want it to:

```html
<span>This is my text, it tells a story about a cat which was</span> 
<span>这是我的文字，它讲述了一个故事一只猫是什么哪</span>
<span>always angry and attacked even humans. One day the cat</span> 
<span>总是生气，甚至攻击人类。有一天，猫</span>
```

It looks like this makes it look exactly how you want it to. This is mainly because this is how you said that you wanted it to look.

Comment: thx for your time. i see the maincontent and the translation mixed :) . Your solution will only work for a tiny range of screen sizes and in the others it will be out of shape. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

These are semantically linked and should be grouped with HTML.

If you want to have this work responsively you will either end up with overflows (scrollable text that has greater width than viewport) or use viewport width relative font size such as vw (https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) and do this "manually" based on max line length